# How to deploy package to Azure Web App using MSDeploy extension? (The value for one of the HTTP headers is not in the correct format)

Tags: azure, azure-storage, msdeploy, webdeploy, azure-resource-manager

I am trying to build a very simple Azure Resource Manager template to provision an App Service Plan, a Web App and immediately deploy package there using MSDeploy. I created a Resource Group project in Visual Studio and added Web App and MSDeploy extension. I basically followed this article: http://blogs.technet.com/b/georgewallace/archive/2015/05/10/deploying-a-website-with-content-through-visual-studio-with-resource-groups.aspx. I haven't customized deployment PowerShell script which comes with the project.

Here is the template: http://pastebin.com/raw/aFsMyg1W

Everything looks like it should work (package is uploaded to blob, web app is created), but deployment fails with message:

> Resource Microsoft.Web/sites/extensions 'xg-test-webapp5/MSDeploy' failed with message 'The resource operation completed with terminal provisioning state 'Failed'.

There is an error message accessible via Kudu console (`LogFiles/SiteExtensions/MSDeploy/appManagerLog.xml`):

> AppGallery Deploy Failed:  'Microsoft.WindowsAzure.StorageClient.StorageClientException: The value for one of the HTTP headers is not in the correct format

Full log:

[image: full log]

Just for the reference, here is the content of the blob where the package was uploaded. It can be seen that it is accessible at the correct URL.

[image: blob]

Any idea what is happening? Thanks

Answer (score 1):

In your ARM template, the **packageUri** property for the **MSDeploy** extension resource is the concatenation of parameters: **_artifactsLocation**, **webdeployPackageFolder** and **_artifactsLocationSasToken**.

I tested your actual web deploy package blob Uri below.
https://xgartifacts.blob.core.windows.net/xg-test-rg-stageartifacts/deploy/package.zip

It is a publicly accessible blob, which means it can be downloaded without the SAS token.

Hence, you should not include the SAS Token in the packageUri property of your ARM template.

Hope this helps!

```
"packageUri": "[concat(parameters('_artifactsLocation'), '/', parameters('webdeployPackageFolder'), '/', parameters('webdeployPackageFileName'), parameters('_artifactsLocationSasToken'))]"
```

Comment: Good catch! I definitely want my blob to be private. I set container as public before for debugging purposes and forgot to change it back.. It is now private again, but unfortunately the same error still happens (`The value for one of the HTTP headers is not in the correct format.`). :( It's a shame that it doesn't say what headers are incorrect.

Comment: No problem. By the way, how long do you set the SAS token expiry period?

Comment: One suggestion I would have is try to use a single parameter for your package Uri to test it. It could probable due to some missing values in your concatenated packageUri.

Comment: SAS token is set to expire in 4 hours. I haven't configured default deployment script which comes with Visual Studio ResourceGroup project type, so I believe that the path should be correct. I've also changed the blob URL to static one before and it didn't work as well. :(

Comment: Can you check to see which version of Azure PowerShell you have installed?  In a PowerShell window, run: (get-module -listavailable azure*storage) and see what you get?

Comment: @bmoore-msft: here is the output: http://i.imgur.com/kTV867h.png. However, I am not sure if I understand how wrong version might have screwed things up here. Packages are uploaded to blob using AzCopy.exe (which comes with Visual Studio RG project) and MSDeploy websites extension downloads it using .NET SDK as can be seen on the screenshot with xml error.

Comment: The 1.0.5 release of the Azure cmdlets changed the way they generate sasTokens (that are used to download the msdeploy package from storage) though I'm not sure that's the problem.  Can you pastebin the PowerShell script from your project (that will inform the version of the SDK you created the project in).  Another thing to try, there is an msdeploy sample template here: https://github.com/bmoore-msft/AzureRM-Samples - can you successfully deploy that template and package using the script from that repo?